# extern C and struct method

Tags: c++, c, struct, extern

Given the following C++ code,

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
        struct foo {
                void getNum() { 
                }
        };
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
        return 0 ;
}
```

Is it possible to call `getNum()` from C?

Comment: This won't compile in C.

Comment: @Bertrand OP want's to compile it in C++, but call it from C.

Comment: @Bertrand: The intent is to call the function from C code.

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I misread the thing.

Comment: How would you call it from C?

Comment: @Martin: See here - http://dsc.sun.com/solaris/articles/mixing.html#cpp_from_c

Comment: @Code: So from C you call a C++ function that happens to have C linkage. Then the C++ function can call the methods on an object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, since `getNum` is a member function, which C doesn't have.

A possible solution to that problem is to write a C++ function to return a `foo` instance as a `foo*` (where `foo` is changed to be an empty struct) to C (I assume this is binary compiled as C++ to which C is linking), then have a free function in C++ called `foo_getNum` or something, which takes a `foo*` (whose definition is modified for the C version to be empty) which calls `getNum` on it. It wouldn't be type safe though, obviously, (but taking a `foo*` even when `foo` is empty would be better than `void*` - thanks David).

Comment: Why is `typedef struct {} foo` better than `typedef void foo` in this case?

Answer (score 7):

The `extern "C"` has no effect on the member function:  `getNum()` has C++ language linkage.

The C++ Language Standard states (C++03 §7.5/4):

> A C language linkage is ignored for the names of class members and the member function
>   type of class member functions.

So, no, you cannot call this function directly from a C program (though, as others have said, you can't compile that code as C anyway because C does not have member functions).  It is of course conceivable that some implementations might allow you to call this function from a C program via some implementation-specific method.

Comment: Intent is to compile with C++ to be linked by a C program.

Answer (score 4):

You can't call that member function from C in a portable way. You need to expose your C++ interface by flattening it.

Comment: Is _flattening_ what I described in my answer? I haven't heard this term before (there are a lot of terms I haven't heard before though).

Comment: @Seth Yes, you are describing what I know as flattening. Incidentally, `void*` is perhaps not the best approach. You can get some type safety by declaring an empty struct and operating with pointers to that struct.

Comment: I believe you, is there an article which I can read explaining why the latter is safer, so I don't have to waste your time making you explain it?

Comment: @Seth Somewhere no doubt there is. I was educated right here on SO by I can't remember who, one of the uber C++ gurus. There's not much to it. In C `void*` is assignment compatible with all pointer types, without casting. So to get some type safety declare your pointer type to point at an empty struct type. Then you can't send C strings to a C++ function expecting an object!!

Comment: @Seth Read here: http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/mixing.html and scroll down to the section titled **Accessing C++ Classes From C**. You can use incomplete struct definitions which is nice.

Answer (score 1):

The code you gave will not compile in C mode as C compiler doesn't support functions in struct. However you can create a function in C++ which can call this and link it with C linkage.
Create 2 files main.c and abc.cpp

Code for main.c

```
extern "C" void getNumCaller();
int main ()
{
    getNumCaller();
    return 0;
}
```

Code for abc.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
        void getNum() {
            std::cout << "calling getNum" << std::endl;
        }
};

extern "C" void getNumCaller()
{
    struct foo abc;
    abc.getNum();
}
```

Compile the code :

```
g++ -o abc abc.cpp main.c
```

and you will get output:

```
calling getNum
```

Comment: This is nearly useful but getNumCaller needs to be passed a pointer to the struct. This is flattening the interface.

Comment: @david What do you mean by flattening the interface? Have never heard of this term